# Fluid crop resize streatches image

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I am using this line to resize an image and crop if needed to get the specific size but the image is coming out stretched.

```
{f:uri.image(image: newsItem.falMediaPreviews.1, width:420c, height:160c)}
```

How do I make the image be scaled in proportion and cropped?

Comment: Are you sure the image gets streched by the viewhelper or could some css code be the reason? From what i see you should get an image of exactly 420x160 pixels cropped out of anything equal or bigger than 420x160px. If using smaller images you may get unsharp images because of upscaling but you should not end up with streched images. Btw: which Version of Typo3 are you running on?

Comment: @FabianSchöner I've inspected the image, it's definitely stretched by the viewhelper. I am using TYPO3 7.6.11

Comment: what are the dimensions of your image input?

Comment: @FabianSchöner My test image is 930w x 700h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you keep the structure of the original News code in place when calling falMediaPreviews, instead of calling it directly in your link.

For example:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.falMediaPreviews}">
    <f:then>
        <f:alias map="{mediaElement: newsItem.falMediaPreviews.1}">
            <f:if condition="{mediaElement.originalResource.type} == 2">
                {f:uri.image(src:mediaElement.uid, treatIdAsReference:1, width:'420c', height: '160c', absolute: '1')}
            </f:if>
        </f:alias>
    </f:then>
</f:if>
```

Not sure if you need all that, but see if the output is still disformed.

Comment: Not in detail, but I remembered having the same issue once, and that fixed it for me ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe...

```
{f:uri.image(image: newsItem.falMediaPreviews.1, minWidth:'420', minHeight:'160', maxWidth:'420', maxHeight:'160', width:'420c', height:'160c')}
```